# Long press drop down menu in windows phone 7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a databound application with data the user can add or remove. I would like the users to option to remove a displayed item on screen by long pressing it and then selecting delete from a drop down list menu. How do I implement this?

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you're looking for the [ContextMenu](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/wp7-contextmenu-answers-to-popular-questions) control from the [Silverlight Toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/).  You can just add a context menu to the DataTemplate of your list with a menu item for Delete, and then remove the selected item in the click event of the menu item.

Comment: I'm trying to use the toolkit but I get an error saying Error 5 Assembly 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference.

Comment: You need to add a reference to Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll in your project.